# What is the value of $\frac{x-y}{z}+\frac{y-z}{x}+\frac{z-x}{y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x,y,z$ are real numbers such that $x,y,z \geq -1$, $xyz\not= 0$ and
\begin{matrix} \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{y+2} +\sqrt{z+3}= \sqrt{y+1} +\sqrt{z+2} + \sqrt{x+3} \\ \sqrt{y+1} + \sqrt{z+2} +\sqrt{x+3} = \sqrt{z+1}+\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{y+3} \end{matrix}
What is the value of $\frac{x-y}{z}+\frac{y-z}{x}+\frac{z-x}{y}$ ?

Thanks for helping solving this problem.

EDIT: I have done 
$(\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{y+2} +\sqrt{z+3})^2$=$ (\sqrt{y+1} +\sqrt{z+2} + \sqrt{x+3})^2$ and  $( \sqrt{y+1} + \sqrt{z+2} +\sqrt{x+3})^2 = (\sqrt{z+1}+\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{y+3})^2$ but haven't recived any helpful things.

Comment: As this expression has cyclic symmetry, we can assume without loss of generality that $x\geq y,z$. The first condition basically tells you that $y\leq z$ because of the way square roots work (essentially if $y\geq z$, then $\sqrt{y+3}+\sqrt{z+2}\leq \sqrt{y+2}+\sqrt{z+3}$). Similarly, the second expression gives us that $y\geq z$. Hence, we can conclude that $y=z$. Now if this condition is true, then $x=y=z$ also. Hence, we're done. Using this, we can find that the expression must equal $0$.

Comment: @fierydemon How did you get $\sqrt{y+3}+\sqrt{z+2}\leq \sqrt{y+2}+\sqrt{z+3}$ from assuming $y \geq z$? I can see $\sqrt{y+3} \geq \sqrt{z+3}$, and $\sqrt{y+2} \geq \sqrt{z+2}$, but the sum is different.

Comment: @Sil- Squaring both sides (and then squaring again after canceling out terms) will convince you of this

Comment: @fierydemon You are right, good!

Answer (score 0):

The only answer that will satisfy the two equations involving square roots is that $$x=y=z$$. $$x$$,$$y$$,and$$z$$ can be any real numbers between -1 and 0 and above 0. If $$x=y=z$$, $$x-y=0$$, $$y-z=0$$, and $$z-x=0$$. So the result will be $$0/z+0/x+0/y$$ and since $$x,y, and z$$ do not equal zero. The resulting equation will equal zero $$0/z+0/x+0/y=0$$.

Comment: Why $x=y=z$ ? What happen to other cases? 
Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the above comments under the original post; there is a more detailed solution.